Identification of cellular membrane damage using a microscope and gram stain
I am observing E.coli under a microscope at 1000x with a gram stain, and I was hoping to identify potential cells with cellular membrane damage.
In my experiment, I had a negative control sample of E.coli and a positive control with penicillin. Both samples were on slides which were then stained and viewed. I know that penicillin would kill the bacteria but I was hoping to see some damage on the bacteria through a microscope.
Is it possible to identify which cells were damaged by the penicillin through a microscope?
Negative Control:

Positive control(Penicillin):


Why would you think you might see this? You should check the mechanism of action of tetracyclines...

Apologies, I used multiple treatments so I confused the tetracycline with penicillin. I edited the question and added the new image.
